# MISRA violation "441 - Float cast to non-float "

Tags: c, misra

I am trying to correct the MISRA violation "441 - Float cast to non-float" that is occurring with the following code:

```
tULong frames = (tULong)(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);
```

`runTimeSeconds` is a `float` and obviously `40.0f` is assigned as a `float`. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no MISRA rule called "441" in any of the MISRAs. The number is some tool-specific number and doesn't tell us anything. It would be helpful to know which version of MISRA-C you are using, as this rule differs between 98/2004 and 2012 versions.

Comment: Are you meaning the version of MISRA that I select in the Code Review Report? Under the Programming Standards Model drop down?

Comment: I have no idea what tool you are using. I mean the version of MISRA-C that your company is using.

Comment: C LDRA Testbed Version 9.5.3 2015

Comment: In order to use MISRA-C, you must use one of the MISRA-C documents from (1998, 2004 or 2012). Each such document has a number of rules. You have to document how you conform to the various rules through a compliance matrix, where one option to demonstrate compliance for a certain rule is to use a static analyser tool. Other rules you could cover by manual code review, compiler warnings etc. Similarly, there will be a deviation process for rules that you do not conform to. Without the original MISRA-C guidelines and your own documentation, you cannot use MISRA-C in a meaningful way.

Comment: So just running a static analyser through some random code and gawk at the various MISRA-C warnings, without even having access to the MISRA-C document gives nothing. You will likely cause more harm than good when working in such a manner. And since LDRA in particular is filled to the brim with false positives, you need to know MISRA-C. Blindly following LDRA will certainly ruin your code and turn safe code into a safety hazard.

Comment: I believe it is MISRA-C: 2004. That is what I have the Programming Standards Model and Rule Reference set to. Sorry I am still very new to MISRA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<math.h>` has a nice family of functions that round and convert in one call.  No cast needed to convert from `float` to `tULong`.  Below has a `(tULong)` cast to handle an integer to integer conversion which may be eliminated depending on unposted issues of range and `tULong` details.

```
#include <math.h>
// long int lrintf(float x);
// long long int llrint(double x);
// 4 others

tULong frames = (tULong) llrintf(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);
```

This rounds rather than truncates like OP's original code.

Comment: I tried "llrintf" as you specified. I end up with a different MISRA issue. You say no cast needed to convert from float to tULong. So drop the tULong as follows:

Comment: tULong frames = (runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);

Comment: @robrwill  What was the " different MISRA issue"?  What is the maximum value of `runTimeSeconds * 40.0f`?

Comment: 435 S Float/Integer conversion without cast

Comment: @robrwill 1) `tULong frames = (tULong) llrintf(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);` should not generate "Float/Integer conversion without cast"  2) For clarity: This answer does not imply "no cast needed to convert from float to tULong" _and_ use `tULong frames = (runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);`.  It is by  using `llrintf()` instead that "no cast needed to convert from float to tULong".

Comment: I was able to get it to a "Conditional Pass" when running my static analysis tool by doing the following, tULong frames = (tULong) llrint(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f); . But still can't figure out why it isn't a "Pass".

Comment: What happens with `tULong frames =  llrint(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);`  (ell-ell, no cast) and `tULong frames =  lrint(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);`  (1 ell, no cast)?

Comment: Why not use `long int lrintf(float x);` which would probably be more correct here?

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps?  It might  be more _efficient_ to use `lrintf()` vs `llrintf()`.  Certainly the wider `llrint()` will not be less functionally correct than `lrint()`.   `tULong`, a non C-standard type, is certainly some unsigned type.  It may equate to `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, or `uintmaxt_t` or ....  We do not know, so going with the with `llrint()` is basically CYA. Code could use some conditional processing to select the most efficient  type. OP later commented the range is up to 435 s, something well within the `long` range,so go with `lrint()` if we want to abide by that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a rule (MISRA-C:2004 10.4) stating the value of a complex expression of floating type may only be cast to a narrower floating type.

`(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f)` is such a so-called *complex expression* (a MISRA-C:2004 term). To dodge the MISRA violation, you can introduce a temporary variable:

```
float tmp = runTimeSeconds * 40.0f;
tULong frames = (tULong)tmp; // no complex expression, this is fine
```

---

The rationale for this rule is that complex expressions could potentially contain implicit type promotions and similar dangerous things.

MISRA-C:2004 is also worried/paranoid about incompetent programmers who think that changing code like `uint8_t u8a, u8b; ... u8a + u8b` into `(uint32_t)(u8a + u8b)` would somehow cause the addition to get carried out as an unsigned 32 bit type.

---

These rules have been improved in MISRA-C:2012 and are more reasonable there. A cast from a float expression to an unsigned one is fine as per MISRA-C:2012 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to truncate the result, use the `truncf` function:

```
ULong frames = truncf(runTimeSeconds * 40.0f);
```

That way, your intention is made explicitly.

Comment: The return value of `truncf()` is a `float` so this does not avoid a cast.